# What's meaning of pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0?

Tags: python, pip

From this [link](https://github.com/openstack/python-openstacksdk/blob/master/requirements.txt)

I want to use pip install all the packages.

But you see this line:

> pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0

what mean of it?

Does it mean the version should `>= 2.0.0` and do not equals to `2.1.0` ?

Does it means I can install it by such as :
`pip install prb ==2.0.1` and `pip install prb ==2.0.6`, can not install by : `pip install prb ==2.1.0`?

And I install it like this:

```
[root@localhost bin]# pip install pbr!=2.1.0 
Collecting pbr!=2.1.0
  Downloading pbr-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 211kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pbr
Successfully installed pbr-3.1.1
```

I am not sure whether there is some thing wrong.

and I can not install like this, who can explain it:

```
[root@localhost bin]# pip install pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0
Invalid requirement: 'pbr!=2.1.0,'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "','"
```

Comment: Yes, it means greater than or equal to 2.0.0 except 2.1.0. If you install 3.1.1 it satisfies both requirements.

Comment: It may not work for you, depending on your version of pip. You'll want to add the pip version to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean the version should >= 2.0.0 and do not equals to 2.1.0 ?

Yes, that it's what it means according to the [pip requeriments file format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format)

```
keyring >= 4.1.1            # Minimum version 4.1.1
coverage != 3.5             # Version Exclusion. Anything except version 3.5
```

Update:

If you are running `pip install pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0` in a bash shell you need to quoted it: `pip install "pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0"` to avoid misinterpretation.

Comment: Can you explain the `pip install pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0`  get error?

Comment: [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) has all the details.

Comment: You need to use `""` to run it. Try this:`pip install "pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0"`